# Cant create relationship in laravel migrations

Tags: laravel, foreign-keys, database-migration

I am trying to make a relationship between "user_id" in members table and "id" in users table. Getting errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed". I am migrating users table before the members table.

```
$table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
   $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
```

Comment: check the domain of the user table id

Comment: have you tried `unsignedBigInteger()`? The default users table migration uses a big int for the ID, instead of a normal int.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is correct, so it's likely one of a couple problems:

1. Your `users` table is not actually called `users`.
2. You actually created the members migration before the users migration, and then went back and edited the members migration. Laravel runs migrations in the order of the timestamp in the filename, so you'll need to either edit the file name of your members migration, or create a new migration with your foreign key definition in it.
3. You're trying to run existing migrations over the top of an existing database. Run `php artisan migrate:refresh` to roll everything back and run it all over again. **Be aware, this will destroy *all* your data**, so make sure it's in a test environment.